# XML node extraction with PHP and simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I am trying to extract values of an XML feed:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

The XML looks like this:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2014-12-14T17:12:13Z" yahoo:lang="en-us">
  <results>
    <rate id="EURUSD">
      <Name>EUR to USD</Name>
      <Rate>1.2463</Rate>
      <Date>12/13/2014</Date>
      <Time>7:23am</Time>
      <Ask>1.2466</Ask>
      <Bid>1.2461</Bid>
    </rate>
  </results>
</query>
```

I tried using the simplexml load file, but it does not work somehow?

```
<?php 
$xmlfile = '$url';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile); 
print $xml->results->rate->name; 
?>
```

Comment: Tip #1: Case matters in XML element names - Tip #2: The answer given is not wrong however print does turn it into as string so the code given there-in is not necessary. --- Summary: You just made a little typo in your code, writing the word "Name" with lowercase first letter "N". That's all. Doing typographical mistakes normally don't count as programming questions so in case you wonder why your question might get closed and eventually disappear from the site, that's the reason then.

Answer (score 1):

$xml->results->rate->Name return a SimpleXMLElement

```
$xml->results->rate->Name->__toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Case matters `name != Name`.

```
print $xml->results->rate->Name;
```

Outputs:

> EUR to USD